# Custom table view cell in storyboard

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, storyboard

I have a pretty strange situation. I use storyboard in order to go with the times. And I have a view controller in which I have `UIScrollView` in which I have UITableView with with custom table view cells. So my question is: how to make a custom table view cell from storyboard inside scroll view, because before I used to make a separate nib with a Custom Cell in it. But now I get this error: 'The NIB data is invalid.' So please, suggest me any solution or idea how to solve my problem. Thank you in advance

Comment: why to add tableview inside scroll view, just create an independent tableview.

Comment: Because I have 2 TableViews inside a scrollView

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turned out that I had checked "Use Autolayout" in the Interface Builder Document pane of the Storyboard file. This throws the "invalid NIB" error when running on iOS 5.